# iOS Image from URL Retina Size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I would like to load some Icons from a Webservice for different sizes (1x, 2x and 3x) - but, when there is no image name with x2 at the end, ios always uses it as 1x.

Ill already found some answers, that you should provide an url with imagename@2x.png - so that iOS could recognize is as Retina Image, but how should that work correct with remote Images for 3 sizes?

In my Case ill got a Webservice, which can provide images in all sizes. I would like to specify with the url the correct size for the device.

For example:

http://example.com/x2/image.png

or

http://example.com/x3/image.png

Normally ill use the Images.xcassets to provide all different sizes, but this time i would like to load the images remotely. How do i check which size is the correct for the used device? Should i ask for the display resolution (or for the iPhone Type?) to check out which image should get loaded?

And how do i say an UIImageView that the Image coming from this Url:

http://example.com/x3/image.png

is 3x (so do not render it 3 times larger) ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale` to know what size you will need. And then load image use this API: `+ (nullable UIImage *)imageWithData:(NSData *)data scale:(CGFloat)scale`. You can specify which scale of the image is.

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

to determine scale of screen.

*in swift:*

```
 UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
```

Or use this follow code:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] && ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0)){
     // Retina display
}else{
    // non-Retina display
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define some macros like,

```
    #define iPad    UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad

    #define iPhone5OrBelow ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height < 667)

    #define iPhone6 ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 667)

    #define iPhone6Plus ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 736)
```

Than you can check any of this macro like,

```
if (iPhone6 || iPhone5OrBelow)
{
 // use @2ximage.png
}
else 
{
 // use @3ximage.png
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

```
You can check for iPhone.

For Ex :
if(iPHone5 || iPhone5S || iPhone6 || iPhone6S){
// load 2x images.
  use this link http://example.com/x2/image.png
  yourImgView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:yourLinkfor2ximage]];

  }
  else if(iPhone6+ || iPhone6+S ){
  //use this link http://example.com/x3/image.png
    yourImgView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:yourLinkfor3ximage]];
  }
```